# Is Zariski closure of finitely generated matrix semigroup computable?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

In general, can the Zariski closure of the semigroup of matrices $\langle M_1, \ldots, M_k \rangle$ be algorithmically computed (at least in theory)?

For this purpose I'm happy to assume the matrices have rational entries, or are otherwise "nice". If the answer is "no", are there known classes of matrices for which these Zariski closures are effectively computable? (I know that the answer is "yes" for unitary matrices over algebraic numbers.)

Comment: What do you mean by computable in this context?  It might not even be countable.

Comment: I'm looking for an effective representation of the Zariski closure, for instance a finite list of the polynomials that generate the corresponding ideal.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has been solved (the answer is 'yes') in the paper *"Polynomial Invariants for Affine Programs"*, by Ehud Hrushovski, Joël Ouaknine, Amaury Pouly, and James Worrell, published in the Proceedings of the 33rd Annual ACM/IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science (LICS) 2018. An author copy is available at
https://people.mpi-sws.org/~joel/publications/zariski18abs.html .

The main result is stated as Theorem 16 (and Corollary 17 for the real Zariski closure) in Section 6 (it applies in fact more generally to *constructible* -- not merely finite -- sets of generators).